# javascript jquery is removing the decimal point and zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing plus minus with plus minus button but when i do it js removes the decimal point and zero's `12.000` after doing plus minus it shows `12` only and i want to keep the decimal point and zero like `12.000`.

Here is the `SPAN` where the result is showing:

```
<span id="product1_total_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>">
</span>
```

How can i fix this issue in my js below:

```
function subtractQty(prITTD){
  var pr = document.getElementById("number_" + prITTD);
  if (pr.value - 1 < 1)
    return;
  else
    pr.value--;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".operator").on('click',function() {
      $("#product1_total_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>").text($("#product1_base_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>").val() * $("#number_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>").val());
  });
});
```

Comment: try using `.toFixed(3)`

Comment: @VuralAcar You mean .toFixed(3) :)

Comment: Yes of course thanks for the correction.

Comment: @VuralAcar would you please tell me where to use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query had to be fixed as in the discussion under the answer of **Vural Acar** i said that we need to merge the queries.

**The below fix solved my problem, actually it has to be fixed. Because this is the result div and the problem was in the result div.**

`($("#product1_base_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>").val() * $("#number_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>").val()).toFixed(3)`

The above is the fix in the below query to keep the decimals inspired from **Vural Acar** Answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".operator").on('click',function() {
      $("#product1_total_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>").text(($("#product1_base_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>").val() * $("#number_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>").val()).toFixed(3));
  });
});
```

The below query is for plus minus button only to do plus minus for the quantity.

```
function subtractQty(prITTD){
  var pr = document.getElementById("number_" + prITTD);
  if (pr.value - 1 < 1)
    return;
  else
    pr.value--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with .toFixed(3)`

example usage:

```
function subtractQty(prITTD) {

  var pr = document.getElementById("number_" + prITTD);

  if (pr.value - 1 < 1)
    return;
  else
    pr.value = parseFloat(--pr.value).toFixed(3);
}
```

fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p37Mx/147/)

Comment: well its the same no change in the result.

Comment: well then it means, your value is string. I ll update with a fix now

Comment: Thats interesting, because I have just tested it and should work, Let me test the values

Comment: can u check the other js code in my question is it causing this issue?? because what you have fixed or fixing it does plus minus and the other one is showing the total of the quantity

Comment: I really don't understand your problem, this is a simple function and should work. Did you checked the fiddle?  and why are you using JS+JQuery, you can use JQuery only?

Comment: Sorry for disturbance i think we need to merge the both of functions up in my question i have updated my question, I have given the Span where the result is showing up. `<span id="product1_total_<?php echo $prITTD; ?>">
</span>`